# Passing multiple handlers to a logger

Tags: python, logging

I have a logging .yaml config file (parital):

```
handlers:
  console:
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    stream: ext://sys.stderr
    formatter: basic
  console_file: 
    class: logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
    filename: bvbot_general.log
    maxBytes: 20000000
    backupCount: 3
    encoding: utf-8
    formatter: basic

loggers:
  general:
    handlers: [console]
    level: DEBUG
    propagate: False
  general_file:
    handlers: [console_file]
    level: DEBUG
    propagate: True

root:
  handlers: [console]
  level: INFO
```

Individually the loggers 'general' and 'general_file' work as expected. But, if I add the 'console_file' handler to logger 'general', I only get output to console and not also to file as anticipated:

```
loggers:
  general:
    handlers: [console, console_file]
    level: DEBUG
    propagate: False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do get your logger? Works fine for me with following code:

```
import os
import logging.config

import yaml

# Loading from logging.yaml
# ...

logger = logging.getLogger('general')
logger.info('hello')
```

Comment: I  was modifying the .yaml in my package as opposed to the one located in my home folder, which takes presidence :( I'll prob remove this question..